# How to post multiple items in one request to an API in a REST(ful) way?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, post

This is a more conceptual question so I think the frameworks used do not matter. Still I'm building an API with Node & Express and the frontend with Angular.

**Scenario**:

A user enters information about a book into a single form. It is then submitted to the API where it should be validated (in addition to frontend validation) and saved to the database.

The form contains information on several models in the database:

- Book: Title, description, etc.
- Author: Many authors have many books
- Publisher: One publisher has many books

If an author or a publisher already exists in the db, it will be linked instead of created.

**Questions:**

I would like to achieve that in one single request.

- What is the correct way to do that?
- Should I just post the formdata to `/api/books` and solve the complexity on the backend side with my ORM and some kind of lifecycle callbacks on the book model that create / link authors and publisher?
- Should my API route reflect that in any way?
- Should I create some kind of virtual model (e.g. `BookCollection`) that reflects the combination of book, authors and publisher?
- Is it ok to also retrieve all three when calling `GET /api/books/:id` ?
- Are there proven ways to handle validation on multiple objects?

Thank you for your input! Anything helps!

Comment: Passing a model `BookCollection` will make it easier since you'll just have to send one object. I think this has to be dealed with in backend. The returned object in fornt end wlll give you informations about what happened and up to you to decide to inform to user of what has been done

Answer (score 3):

Here are my thoughts on this:

1. Keep your APIs as clean as possible. Messing with the API is calling for trouble in the not too distant future. So, I'd recommend having the api as /api/books.
2. Your book entry form would have fields for authors and publishers right? I think you'd like to have a dropdown/typeahead with existing authors and publishers from which the user entering the book details will select 1 (or more), right? In that case your book model should have Ids of authors and publishers. This is fine. The definition of the book requires that you have these cross functional fields (but only the Ids). So you should have 3 endpoints for all these: /api/books, /api/authors and /api/publishers.
3. When you're showing the book details on a page (Show Book perhaps) then you'll have to decide whether you want to get author and publisher details in one call via a complex API or make three calls to get relevant data. The latter option is cleaner and more extensible and I'd go for it. You can assemble all this data on server side and it'll be faster but you're then building bulky non-reusable API which only serve your specific purpose (which may change later). So, to summarize when showing book make 3 API calls to get book details and then two more to get author and publisher details based on the ids received from book api.
4. Let's take two scenarios: 1st when book has author/publisher which is in your database. In this case the user can select them from the typeahead and save the ids. 2nd when user doesn't select any author/publisher from the typeahead. In this case your model will have publisherId and authorId as null. When you receive this request at /api/books you can initiate creation of both author and publisher and update the book object in db with their ids.
5. Please note that doing so will not stop you from implementing your validations on server. You can still validate at server side but it makes your client side architecture much cleaner. And also, your API is modular enough to be consumed by multiple consumers.

Comment: Thanks. About the form: No, dropdown is not an option. It has to be possible to just type in the name. I then normalize it, look it up and create or link the authors. Books/authors are just a theoretical example, in my case I deal with other data and there won't be two 'authors' with the same name. About validation: I have to validate all three models. Let's say the book details are fine and I create it and then go to the author. But the author isn't valid. I now have a book without author and it might be dificult to get meaningful error messages back to the user and not end up in data hell.

Comment: Ok. My first advice would be to seriously consider the angular typeahead component here - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead. What it does is to show you a textbox which is bind to a list and when you type it gives you matching values from the list. This is exactly what you require. This way the user will not type an author/publisher that doesn't exist in your db (if you want that functionality then you can still use typeahead and handle that case differently).

Comment: Also, the typeahead will save you from needing to perform tedious validations on authors and publishers objects.

Comment: Well as I said I WANT the user to be able to enter an author that does not exist. That is the whole point.

Comment: I disagree with the validations. Only validating on the frontend side is not an option. Angular is just one way to post to this api. In the future there could be others. And just validating on the frontend is bad practice. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new model `BookCollection` is the good solution *(for me)*. You have to generate a new route on the server side : `/api/bookcollection`

But then, you should **avoid to duplicate all the data manipulation** on the server. You should reuse the code from `/api/book` to store books, the code from `/api/authors` to store the authors etc. Or you will soon have big problem to maintain duplicated codes.

`/api/bookcollection` should check if all data are correct BEFORE adding each one of them.